# Копирование значений словаря в многомерный список Python (проблема с обьектами)

Tags: python, list, словари

Есть словарь с ролями игроков (ключ - название класса, например 'Mage', значение - массив с параметрами класса (хп, урон, броня и т.д.))

```
CHARACTERS = {'Mage': ['Mage', 0, 1, 60, 2, 100],
              'Tank': ['Tank', 0, 2, 30, 1, 250],
              'Warrior': ['Warrior', 0, 1.5, 45, 1, 150],
              'Healer': ['Healer', 0, 1.2, 35, 0, 150]}
```

Когда пользователь выбирает себе роль, я создаю и наполняю список с игроками (units), добавляя значения из словаря.
Вот как я это делаю:

```
units.append(CHARACTERS.get(role)
```

Проблема заключается в том, что при использовании этого метода, двух 'Mage' или двух 'Warrior' в игре быть не может - при изменении параметров одного из Mage, параметры другого так же меняются.
Я выяснил, что id у добавляемых мной обьектов `id(users[0])` и `id(users[1])` одинаковые, если игрок с нулевым индексом и первым оба выбрали 'Mage'..

Но как сделать так, чтобы id элементов списка были разные, какой командой добавлять элементы в список?

Comment: создайте копию объекта `CHARACTERS["Mage"].copy()`

Comment: не лучше сделать через класы и клепать объекты как угодно ?